# Probablity distribution of bend angle in gromacs

Tags: biochemistry, computational-chemistry

In an analysis I got the probability distribution of a bend angle $P(\theta)$ with respect to time. However, I need to plot $P(\theta)$ with respect to $1- \cos(\theta)$ where $\theta$ refers to the bend angle in B-DNA.

Is there any command or procedure employed for it in GROMACS?

Comment: Why won't you export data to do it externally?